# Broadcast Receiver in Application class android

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

I am registering `BroadcastReceiver` in application class and its register method is getting called and completed successfully without issue during application start. I am sending a broadcast from the module. I can print the action, it is there. But the app is not catching the broadcast. I don't know where I am doing wrong.

Below is the method to register receiver.

```
fun registerRecordingDataReceiver () {
    info("AppReceiver register called=>${CommonsDataVars.TEMPERATURE.action()}")
    val temperatureCompleted = CommonsDataVars.TEMPERATURE.action()
    val temperatureCompletedIntentFilter = IntentFilter(temperatureCompleted)
    val broadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
    broadcastManager.registerReceiver(appReceiver,temperatureCompletedIntentFilter)
    info("AppREceiver register completed")
}
```

Part of Broadcast Receiver

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
val action = intent?.getAction()
debug("Action in App Receiver =>"+action)
if (action == CommonsDataVars.TEMPERATURE.action()) {
    info("AppReceiver****************************************")
```

sendBroadcast part:

```
info("TEMPERATURE register called=>${CommonsDataVars.TEMPERATURE.action()}")
val intent = Intent()
intent.setAction(CommonsDataVars.TEMPERATURE.action())
//intent.putExtra(CommonsDataVars.TEMPERATURE.name, temperatureData)
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent)
```

Comment: is that java? what programming language do you use?

Comment: This is kotlin (swift for android)